# Formula to determine how many days have passed using year and Julian date

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have a form I built in Excel that uses the MID formula to deconstruct an eight digit numeric code (like `15317087`) into three parts, and produces a corresponding output for each piece. The first part `15` is the year. The second part is the Julian day `317` and the last part `087` represents a county number the code was mailed in from.

Here's how it looks:

[image: Picture]

Notice how `15` isn't used. This is because on another page I have a number representing the total number of days passed between 2015 and... well whatever the initial "0 date" is in Excel. As it would happen, that number for 2015 is `42002`. To produce the Gregorian date, I use:

```
INT(SUM(MID(A2,3,3), 'Date Conversion'!A$1))
```

which just adds that number to the Julian date.

The problem is next year I will have to change the `Date Conversion'!A$1` value from 42002 to 42002 + 365 manually, because not every year has the same number of days. Is there some mathematical way to account for this, or must I update the field manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to run into a y3k problem, you could convert the '15' into a year as follows:

```
=DATE(2000+VALUE(LEFT(A2,2)),1,1)
```

This give you Jan 1 of whatever year is in the left 2 numbers, resetting to the year 2000 during calendar year 3000. Presumably changing the formula at that time will not be burdensome.

So, the Julian calendar used by Excel shows Jan 1 2015 (per my above formula) as 42005 [number of days since Jan 1 1900]. This can then be inserted into your conversion to Gregorian.

Comment: No you're right. I was confused because I haven't touched this sheet for months. I forgot for a moment how dates worked. This solution is sufficient thank you!

EDIT: The reason that I was using 42002 as a place holder for 2015 is because I derived that number from trial and error while trying to produce a specific gregorian date from a correlating specific julian date. I'm a little confused about why we have different numbers as well. For now, I shall just subtract 3 from your formula to make it work. I'll figure out the what is causing the difference later.